# Question about Integration by Parts (LIATE)

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

I know that when you do Integration by Parts, you usually choose your u based on LIATE. But what if you were integrating a product of three functions? Say if you were integrating $x  \csc(x)  \log(\cos(x))$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. What would you choose as your $u$ and $dv$?

Comment: Is "LIATE" one of those acronyms you yankees use? ;P Seriously though, what does it stand for?

Comment: Logarithmic, Inverse Trig, Algebraic, Trig, Exponential

Comment: Lot's of this is simply intutition. In general, you just think about the derivatives and antiderivatives of each function (both along and multipled with each other function in this case). In this case I see the logarithm and I instantly want to differentiate it, because the $\csc x$ could cancel. You then just check out if it works... if it doesn't you try something else

Comment: Please use LaTex in your posts.

Comment: @WhyDoYouCare, why would I stop commenting? The comments are intended to improve the post. The only alternative for me is downvoting or voting to close your questions. Which I don't really want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind acronyms: the basic idea is that you hope to end up with something easier (or at least no harder) than what you started with.  If you write your integral as $\int u\; dv$, the $dv$ will need to be integrated and the $u$ differentiated.  Usually integration is going to be where complications set in.  So what term or product of terms can  you integrate here without getting something horrible?

Well, actually, none of them is going to work.  The closest is $dv = x \; dx$ which gives you $v = x^2/2$, but that gives you

$$ \frac{x^2}{2}\csc \left( x \right) \ln  \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) -\int \frac{{x}^{2}}{2} \left( -\csc \left( x \right) \cot
 \left( x \right) \ln  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) -\sec(x)
 \right) \,{\rm d}x
$$

and that seems worse than before.

In fact, in this case I'm pretty sure there is no closed-form antiderivative.
Integration by parts doesn't always help!

On the other hand, if it had been $\int x \sin(x) \ln(\cos(x))\; dx$, you could take $dv = \sin(x) \ln(\cos(x))$.